# Javascript: Array inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a ASP.NET API that expects a string model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(string model)
{

    var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomModel>(model);

    ...

}
```

So far, I have been doing this to pass data to it:

```
var addModel = {
    "SomeValue": {
        "Some": "example",
        "Value": "example"
    },
    "AnotherValue": "example"
}

var model = JSON.stringify(addModel);
```

And it works just fine. But now I need to ship data this way:

```
var addModel = {
    "SomeValue": {
        "Some": "example",
        "Value": "example"
    },
    "AnotherValue": "example",

    "MyArray[0].SomeValue": 1,
    "MyArray[0].AnotherValue": a,
    "MyArray[1].SomeValue": 1,
    "MyArray[1].AnotherValue": a,
}
```

How do I add `MyArray` to the object so it can be passed to the back-end in the proper format?

Comment: i guess i do not understand you correctly...`{ "key": []}` this is the way to add an array into an object

Comment: You can also push into the array with `addModel.MyArray.push(  { "SomeValue" : 1, "AnotherValue": a })` after `addModel` is declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put them in directly with

```
addModel.MyArray[0] = { "SomeValue" : 1, "AnotherValue": a };
```

You can push into the array with

```
addModel.MyArray.push( { "SomeValue" : 1, "AnotherValue": a });
```

after `addModel` is declared

Answer (score 2):

Just declare it as an array like so

```
var addModel = {
    "SomeValue": {
        "Some": "example",
        "Value": "example"
    },
    "AnotherValue": "example",    
    "MyArray": [
        { "SomeValue" : 1, "AnotherValue": a },
        { "SomeValue" : 1, "AnotherValue": a }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"MyArray": [
 {
    "SomeValue": 1,
    "AnotherValue": a
 },
 {
    "SomeValue": 1,
    "AnotherValue": a
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [
    {
        "a":1,
        "b":2
    },
    {
        "a":1,
        "b":2
    }
];

var addModel = {
    "SomeValue": {
        "Some": "example",
        "Value": "example"
    },
    "AnotherValue": "example",
    "myArray": myArray
};
```